# Versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-location are mismatched

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

My App uses 2 aar libraries. One aar is built with com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1', and another is built with com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0. However, I cannot make any change from the 2 libraries. When App uses the version 21.0.1, I can make the build, but get the error when the class in library from 17.0.0 is called.

Error: Found interface e7.c, but class was expected (declaration of 'e7.c' appears in /data/app/.../base.apk

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs'
implementation(name: "a-locatio-17.0.0", ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: "b-location-21.0.1", ext: 'aar')

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20"
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
```

}

Any solution?

Comment: Include the error and your dependencies and classpath  here.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use one gms version at a time. In manifest you can write the exclusion logic for which version you want to keep and which version you want to omit. This can help you to avoid crash in runtime.